# Writing strings to a file

Tags: c, strings

This opens a file and writes 5120 times a string to it, and if the file doesn't exist it creates a new file. The name of the file and the string are chosen randomly. I would like to know if there is a way to speed up this code. It takes about 10 seconds at the moment. I was wondering if I did a recursion in the `escreve()` function or if I create some space in memory with `malloc()` on the main and free it before each cycle. If it will speed the thing up.

```
#define linhas 1024
#define vezes 5120
char *ficheiros[5]={"SO2014-0.txt","SO2014-1.txt","SO2014-2.txt","SO2014-3.txt","SO2014-4.txt"};
char *cadeias[10]={"aaaaaaaaa\n","bbbbbbbbb\n","ccccccccc\n","ddddddddd\n","eeeeeeeee\n","fffffffff\n","ggggggggg\n","hhhhhhhhh\n","iiiiiiiii\n","jjjjjjjjj\n"};

int random(int range)
{
    int num;
    num = rand() % range;
    return num;
}

void escreve(char *fi,char *cad){
    int l;
    int file = open(fi, O_WRONLY | O_CREAT, S_IRWXU | S_IROTH ) ;
    for(l=0;l<linhas;l++)
        write(file,cad, strlen(cad));
    close(file);
}


int main(){
    int x,y,l,i;
    srand(time(NULL));
for(i=0; i<vezes; i++){
    x= random(5);
        y=random(10);
        escreve(ficheiros[x],cadeias[y]);

}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: ok so after trying for a bit i figured that if i dont close(file) it speeds up alot. it takes 2 seconds now. but i think faster it's still possible. i also tryed the escreve function has a recurssion it didnt  change the time. any ideas?

Comment: Use English variable names,function names,comments. example : `ficheiros` -> `file_names`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a very instructive example of wrong judgement. I understand (correct me if I am wrong) that you went for a low-level `write` to avoid seemingly unnecessary overhead of `FILE *` functions offered by a `stdio` library. Not only it made your code less portable, it in fact made id slower!

The net effect is that your code invokes a system call for each 10 characters.

System call is an extremely expensive operation. It involves switching memory maps from a user to a kernel space, and on top of that it faces who knows how many cache misses. This is exactly the problem `stdio` solves by internal buffering.

This is how your original code behaves:

```
~/projects/play/cr/pedro $ time ./original 

real    0m7.929s
user    0m0.484s
sys     0m7.432s
```

I changed opening a file to

```
FILE * file = fopen(fi, "w");
```

and writing to it to

```
    fputs(cad, file);
```

and the new timigs are

```
~/projects/play/cr/pedro $ time ./with-stdio 

real    0m0.908s
user    0m0.276s
sys     0m0.584s
```

PS To make it a code review:

You shall `#include` at least `<sys/types.h>, <sys/stat.h>, <fcntl.h>` and `<time.h>`.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't changed the performance aspect much, but I have nonetheless made lots of improvements with regard to syntax, readability, portability and conformity to modern C coding standards:

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <unistd.h>

// Compile with -std=c11 (or -std=c99)

// Use uppercase for constants
#define LINHAS 1024
#define VEZES 5120
// If you're going to hardcode your filenames, better make them macros too.
#define FICHEIROS {"SO2014-0.txt", \
                   "SO2014-1.txt", \
                   "SO2014-2.txt", \
                   "SO2014-3.txt", \
                   "SO2014-4.txt"}
#define CADEIAS {"aaaaaaaaa\n", \
                 "bbbbbbbbb\n", \
                 "ccccccccc\n", \
                 "ddddddddd\n", \
                 "eeeeeeeee\n", \
                 "fffffffff\n", \
                 "ggggggggg\n", \
                 "hhhhhhhhh\n", \
                 "iiiiiiiii\n", \
                 "jjjjjjjjj\n"}
#define CAD_SIZE 10

// Convenient macro for whenever you need to loop through a static size array.
// Calculated at compile time.
#define ELEMENT_C(a) (sizeof(a) / sizeof((a)[0]))

// Always include prototypes of all your functions.
// Try to use English for variables and function names as much as possible.
// I'm not sure what they mean, so I haven't translated them here though.
int main(void);
int random(const int range);
void escreve(const int fd, const char *cad);

// Functions without arguments should have the word "void" between parentheses.
int main(void) {
    // time_t is not guaranteed to be unsigned (I think), so cast explicitly
    // for portability.
    srand((unsigned) time(NULL));
    // No need to specify an array size. The compiler will count it by itself.
    const char *ficheiros[] = FICHEIROS,
               *cadeias[] = CADEIAS;

    // Open all files before writing anything. Your code calls open() for every
    // call to escreve(). Seems like a bad idea to me.
    int fds[ELEMENT_C(ficheiros)];
    // Being able to declare variables inside loops is a nice feature of C99
    // onward. In general, tight scoping can prevent many kinds of bugs and
    // makes debugging easier.
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < ELEMENT_C(ficheiros); i++) {
        fds[i] = open(ficheiros[i], O_WRONLY | O_CREAT, S_IRWXU | S_IROTH);
        // Always check the return value of library functions for errors.
        if (fds[i] == -1) {
            // Use strerror() or perror() to get useful debug information
            fprintf(stderr, "Failed to open() %s: %s\n", ficheiros[i],
                    strerror(errno));
            // Use these stdlib macros for more readable return values.
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < VEZES; i++) {
        escreve(fds[random(ELEMENT_C(ficheiros))],
                cadeias[random(ELEMENT_C(cadeias))]);
    }

    // Close all files after writing everything.
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < ELEMENT_C(ficheiros); i++) {
        if (close(fds[i]) == -1) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Failed to close() %s: %s\n", ficheiros[i],
                    strerror(errno));
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }
    }
    // Don't forget to return your exit code at the end of main.
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

int random(const int range) {
    // This is the proper way to use rand().
    // Your version suffers from rounding errors.
    return rand() / (double) (RAND_MAX + 1) * range;
}

void escreve(const int fd, const char *cad) {
    for (int i = 0; i < LINHAS; i++) {
        if (write(fd, cad, CAD_SIZE) == -1) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Failed to write() %s to file descriptor %d: %s\n",
                    cad, fd, strerror(errno));
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
    }
}
```